# Different way solving limit $\lim \limits_{ x\rightarrow 0 }{ { x }^{ x } } $

Tags: real-analysis, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I know how to solve this problem by using L'Hospital's rule

$$\lim \limits_{ x\rightarrow 0 }{ { x }^{ x } } =\lim\limits _{ x\rightarrow 0 }{ { e }^{ x\ln { x }  } } =\lim\limits _{ x\rightarrow 0 }{ { e }^{ \frac { \ln { x }  }{ \frac { 1 }{ x }  }  } } =\lim\limits _{ x\rightarrow 0 }{ { e }^{ \frac { \frac { 1 }{ x }  }{ \frac { 1 }{ { x }^{ 2 } }  }  } } ={ e }^{ 0 }=1,$$

what other different ways can you suggest or show.thanks

Comment: Note, that you forgot a sign in the last step before $e^0$, although this plays no role because the exponent tends to $0$.

Comment: I even have a handbook where this sign was forgotten.

Comment: What about the limit on the complex plane?

Comment: How do we know x^x is even a real function?

Comment: When $x$ is negative, $x^x$ is defined as a real number only when $x$ is rational with an odd denominator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a *basic fact*, seen in high school, that $\lim_{x\to0_+}x\ln x=0$. Hence $x^x$ tends to $1$ as $x\to 0_+$

Comment: @The End: You're right. Thank you for pointing the typo.

Answer (score 3):

If we set $x=e^{-t}$, then $x\to0^+$ as $t\to\infty$ and
$$
x^x=e^{\large-te^{-t}}\tag{1}
$$
Since $1+t\le e^t$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$, we get, for $t\ge0$,
$$
\frac{t^2}4\lt\left(1+\frac t2\right)^2\le e^t\tag{2}
$$
Thus, for $t\gt0$,
$$
0\lt te^{-t}\lt\frac4t\tag{3}
$$
Thus,
$$
e^{\large-\frac4t}\le e^{-te^{-t}}\le1\tag{4}
$$
Let $t\to\infty$, and the Squeeze Theorem says that
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}x^x=\lim_{t\to\infty}e^{\large-te^{-t}}=1\tag{5}
$$

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by Bernard, that is the same as showing that
$$ \lim_{x\to 0^+} x\log x = 0 \tag{1}$$
or, by setting $x=e^{-t}$,
$$ \lim_{t\to +\infty} t e^{-t} = 0\tag{2} $$
that follows by squeezing: for any $t>0$, $e^t>1+t+\frac{t^2}{2}$, hence:
$$ 0\leq \lim_{t\to +\infty} te^{-t} \leq \lim_{t\to +\infty}\frac{t}{1+t+\frac{t^2}{2}}=0.\tag{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the inequality $$\log x < x - 1\tag{1}$$ for $x > 1$. If $x > 1$ then $\sqrt{x} > 1$ and hence $$0 < \log \sqrt{x} < \sqrt{x} - 1 < \sqrt{x}$$ or $$0 < \log x < 2\sqrt{x}$$ or $$0 < \frac{\log x}{x} < \frac{2}{\sqrt{x}}$$ Taking limits as $x \to \infty$ and using Squeeze theorem we get $$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\log x}{x} = 0\tag{2}$$ Letting $t = 1/x$ we get $$\lim_{t \to 0^{+}}t\log t = 0\tag{3}$$ which is equivalent to $$\lim_{t \to 0^{+}}t^{t} = 1$$ as desired.