# Value of the limit at $x=0$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

What is $$\lim_{x \to  0^+} \left((x\cos(x))^x+(x\sin(x)\right)^{1/x}?$$ I substituted $x = 0+h$ and used that near $0, \cos(h) \approx 1, \sin(h)\approx h$ to get the new limit as $$\lim_{h \to 0} \left(h^h+h^{2/h}\right).$$

But now the problem is the second term. How to reduce it to form like $0/0,\infty/\infty$? Thanks.

Comment: Did you expand cos and sin

Comment: Does the question say not to use L-hopital's rule ?

Comment: The parentheses are mismatched.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**. As $x \to 0^+$, one may use the Taylor series expansion of $\sin x$, getting
$$
\begin{align}
\sin (x)&=x+O(x^3),
\\\\ \log(\sin (x))&=\log\left(x+O(x^3)\right)=\log x+O(x^2),
\\\\ \frac{\log(\sin (x))}x&=\frac{\log x}x+O(x),
\end{align}
$$ giving, as $x \to 0^+$,
$$
\begin{align}
\left(x\cos(x))^x+(x\sin(x)\right)^{1/x}&=e^{\large x\log x + x\log\left(\cos x \right)}+e^{\large \frac{\log x}x + \large \frac{\log\left(\sin x \right)}x}
\\\\ &\to e^{0+0}+0
\\\\ &\to 1.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: why did you introduce the log

Comment: @ArchisWelankar This is how we define $a^b$: $a^b=e^{b\log a}$, $a>0$.

Comment: Oh completely missed that out.

Answer (score 3):

There is a mismatch of parentheses in the question as asked. One possible correction is
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0}\left((x\cos(x))^x+x\sin(x)\right)^{1/x}
&=\lim_{x\to0}x\cos(x)\cdot\lim_{x\to0}\left(1+\frac{x\sin(x)}{(x\cos(x))^x}\right)^{1/x}\\
&=0\cdot1
\end{align}
$$
Note that $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\left(1+\frac{x\sin(x)}{(x\cos(x))^x}\right)^{1/x}$ is between $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\left(1+ax\right)^{1/x}$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\left(1-ax\right)^{1/x}$ for any positive $a$.

---

Another is
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0}\left((x\cos(x))^x+(x\sin(x))^{1/x}\right)
&=\lim_{x\to0}x^x\cdot\lim_{x\to0}\cos(x)^x+\lim_{x\to0}x^{1/x}\cdot\lim_{x\to0}\sin(x)^{1/x}\\
&=1\cdot1+0\cdot0
\end{align}
$$
For $\lim\limits_{x\to0}x^x$, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1848067). The other limits are easier.

Answer (score 1):

First, a good idea is to use **WolframAlpha** to get an idea of what the solution should be (and possibly also an idea of how to solve it).

Here's the result of WolframAlpha as image: [WolframAlpha Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChlZU.jpg)

So, the result is $1$. But how do we get to it? We will use **L'Hospital** in a different way than you thought. First, let's simplify a bit:
$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \left((x \cos(x))^x + (x \sin(x))^{\frac{1}{x}}\right) = \lim_{x \to 0^+} (x \cos(x))^x + \lim_{x \to 0^+} (x \sin(x))^{\frac{1}{x}}$$
Lets now compute the first expression. We want to somehow extract the exponent from the expression. This can be done with the following trick:
$$a^b = e^{\log(a^b)} = e^{b \cdot \log(a)}$$
The trick works for real numbers as $\log$ is the inverse function of $e$, not for complex (there $\log$ is not bijective).

$$(x \cos(x))^x = e^{\log((x \cos(x))^x)} = e^{x \cdot \log(x \cos(x))}$$

Okay, now we want to know what $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} x \cdot \log(x \cos(x))$ is. Let's do a little trick and then use **L'Hospital**.
$$\lim_{x \to 0} x \cdot \log(x \cos(x)) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\log(x \cos(x))}{\frac{1}{x}} \stackrel{LH}{=} \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\frac{1}{x \cos(x)} \cdot \left(1 \cdot \cos(x) + x \cdot (-\sin(x))\right)}{-\frac{1}{x^2}}\\
= \lim_{x \to 0} -x^2 \frac{\cos(x) - x \sin(x)}{x \cos(x)} = \lim_{x \to 0} -x^2 \frac{1}{x} \left(\frac{\cos(x)}{\cos(x)} - \frac{x \sin(x)}{\cos(x)}\right)\\
= \lim_{x \to 0} -x \left(1 - x \tan(x)\right) = 0$$

Well, if we go back we now have $e^0 = 1$, thus the left expression converges to $1$.
$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} (x \cos(x))^x = 1$$

Last we need to show that the right expression converges to $0$. We will use a similar approach.
$$(x \sin(x))^{\frac{1}{x}} = e^{\frac{1}{x} \log(x \sin(x))}$$

Again, we are interested what the value for $\exp$ does when converging to $0$. But this time the direction is important ($-\infty$ from right and $\infty$ from left). Also remember, by the product rule, the limit of a product is the product of the limits if neither approaches to $0$.
$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\log(x \sin(x))}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{1}{x} \cdot \lim_{x \to 0^+} \log(x \sin(x)) = -\infty$$

The later is true since informally $\log$ (as $\exp$) converges *faster than other functions*. You may google for a formal description and proof if you're not familiar with that.
Okay, we now have $e^{-\infty}$ for the second part, which converges to $0$.

In total we have:
$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \left((x \cos(x))^x + (x \sin(x))^{\frac{1}{x}}\right) = \lim_{x \to 0^+} (x \cos(x))^x + \lim_{x \to 0^+} (x \sin(x))^{\frac{1}{x}} = 1 + 0 = 1$$

And are finished. I hope you understood everything :)